# Recommended Source Control setup for single developer on single machine

Tags: development, virtual-machine, source-control

I'm curious about what kind of setup other single developers have for their source control. Do you install your source control system (e.g. TFS) on the same machine as SharePoint, do you use a separate machine, do you use virtual machines, etc.

For example, I have SharePoint 2010 runnning in a virtual machine on my laptop, and I am now wondering whether I should install TFS on that same machine, in a separate VM (though that would of course increase the resources required on the laptop). The big benefit of using a separate machine is of course that I could use it with any other VMs as well (though there's only a SharePoint 2007 VM at the moment, that I might not use very often anyway). As I'm the only one developing here, and as I currently plan to work in a single VM only, I am more inclined to do everything inside that single VM.

Comment: Looking at this question and the answers it's created, it appears to be about source control not SharePoint, hence I'm closing as off-topic. It would be better asked at [SO]. You may find [How do you do version/source control in SharePoint?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/how-do-you-do-version-source-control-in-sharepoint) useful.

Comment: I thought there might be SharePoint specific answers, thus I asked it here instead of Stack Overflow. But thanks everyone for your replies anyway!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest TortioiseSVN and VisualSVN Server. Both free if you use the VisualSVN standard edition (http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). This should be more than enough for a single developer.

Best bet would be to setup VisualSVN on a separate server/virtual machine.

Comment: We use SVN for source control for a team of around 5 SharePoint devs. It works well and took me about 2 hours in total to set up. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If you are single developer you really do not need TFS, that's an overkill. You can look at open source alternatives like Subversion or Mercurial.

Here is what you should do:

- Always install your source control system on a dedicated server
- Source control server should be part of regular company backup operations. (Your laptop is not the best place to save your code. If your laptop gets stolen your code will too.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are the only person developing at your company, it might make more sense to get them to pay for an account at a dedicated source control hosting company like [Codesion](http://codesion.com/products/team-edition.html#features).  That gets you cheap and accessible source control and nobody at the company has to worry about maintaining the server/VM for it.